# SQL search and insert with an array in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to to search in my database with an array I get from a drop-down-box, and then after search for that instance I try to insert it into my table. Heres what I have so far.

Controller:

```
public function insertTable() {
$text = $this->input->post('text');
$value['value'] = $this->input->post('value');
        print_r($value);
$data = $this->myModel->insertTo($value,$text);
}
```

Model:(note table1 has an auto incremented id value which is a foreign key in table2)

```
public function insertTo($value,$text){
    $this->db->insert('table1', array('text' => $text);
    $id = $this->db->insert_id();
    foreach ($value as $v) {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('Table3', array('value' => $v));
        $result = $query->result();
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $vID = $row->vID;
        }
        $this->db->insert('Table2', array('ID' => $id, 'vID' => $vID));
    }
}
```

So as you can see I first insert a value to table1 and getting the primary key `id` value inside of it, then I have a `foreach` loop which loops for every value in the `$value` array. I query this in my database save the value and insert. When doing this though I get the following error:

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM (`Table3`) WHERE `value` = Array

Filename: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/CI/models/myModel.php

Line Number: 24
```

So my question is where have I gone wrong? How should I query a database with an array of values and then insert it into a database?

An example of this for an instance would be:

```
$value = 'hello','goodbye','morning';
//lets say when the array value is 0
$query = $this->db->get_where(table3, array('value' => 'hello');
//say this query returns 1
$this->db->insert('Table2', array('ID' => $id, 'vID' => '1');
```

And I want this to happen for every value in the array, so next time we would search by `goodbye` and the id is `2` and that would get inserted in `table2`

Answer (score 0):

To use an array in where clause you can do like this :

```
$ids = join(',',$array);  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($ids)";
```

Comment: Ok, can you tell me why I would need to use a join? And what is the need for the `,`?

Comment: can you show me an exemple for your : $value?
You want that a field can be equal to several value no?
So you have to create a query like : WHERE Table3 IN (exp1, exp2, etc..)
Maybe i don't understand your question

Comment: Have a look at the post now

Answer (score 0):

@Tosx's answer is correct, but to expand on this and provide a Codeigniter Active record implementation:

You could use ActiveRecord chaining to build your query:

```
$valueArray = array('Frank', 'Todd', 'James');

$this->db->select('vID')->from('table3')->where_in('value', $valueArray);
$query = $this->db->get();
// Produces: SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE value IN ('Frank', 'Todd', 'James')
```

Alternatively you could use an associative array to search multiple columns:

```
$array = array('name' => $name, 'title' => $title, 'status' => $status);
$this->db->where($array); 
$query = $this->db->get(table3);
// Produces: SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE name = 'Joe' AND title = 'boss' AND status = 'active'
```

There's great documentation on CI ActiveRecord here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select

Comment: I still get the same unknown column error when I try this method, any idea why?

Comment: Are you sure there is a column named 'value' in your table3?